# Identifying when a sequence stops

Tags: r, sequence

new here so apologies if this question has been answered before. I am trying to identify a sequence within a dataset.

Example:

| id | lengthofstay |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

Then I want to create a variable that will be 0 when the sequence is still going and 1 when the sequence ends.

E.g.

| id | lengthofstay | newvariable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |

Thank you in advance for your help. Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to be of use.

I am quite new to R so I apologize but I am at a loss to where to start. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: For next time: post your data as code, not as text. You can see how to do this in the answers of Mislav Sagovac and myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ave` + `max`

```
> transform(df, newvariable = +(ave(lengthofstay, id, FUN = max) == lengthofstay))
  id lengthofstay newvariable
1  1            1           0
2  1            2           0
3  1            3           1
4  2            1           0
5  2            2           1
6  3            1           0
7  3            2           0
8  3            3           0
9  3            4           1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that the difference between consecutive elements in a series is always larger than zero, unless the series restarts:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  lengthofstay = c(1:3, 1:2, 1:4)
)
df$newvariable <- c(diff(df$lengthofstay) <= 0, 1)
df
##   id lengthofstay newvariable
## 1  1            1           0
## 2  1            2           0
## 3  1            3           1
## 4  2            1           0
## 5  2            2           1
## 6  3            1           0
## 7  3            2           0
## 8  3            3           0
## 9  3            4           1
```

This solution does not make use of the column `id` but only relies on `lengthofstay`.

Comment: Its a great solution, though takes into assumption that the data is arranged as the given example. If random, then it will fail

Comment: Well, yes, obviously. The same is true for the other solutions. There is some information that you need about the series in order to talk about the end of a series and the start of a new one. Alternatively, you could of course build a solution that only relies on the column `id`, which could be done similarly: a new series starts when `id` is incremented.

Comment: Not true about the other solutions. Eg the data.table solution and the base R using ave solution will give the end regardless as to whether the data is ordered or not.

Comment: No, they won't. They only work, if the last number in the sequence is also the highest one.

Comment: Thats incorrect. eg `ave(c(3, 2, 1), c(1,1,1), FUN=max) == max(c(3,2,1))` will give `1,0,0` . Which works as intended. Note that you are obtaining `max` per group. Whether the max is the last or first, it will be obtained. And `1` will be returned at the `max` position

Comment: Yes, exactly. But the question was not about the maximum of the series, but about the last number in the series.

Comment: Which is determined by the maximum value of `lengthofstay`. Anyway, sorry if I disturbed. maybe just understood wrongly.

Comment: Yes, when the numbers are ordered as they are. But not if they are ordered randomly. In the case of c(3, 2, 1), 1 would be the last number in the series, which is not equal to the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

data.table solution

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 4)),
  lengthofstay = c(1:3, 1:2, 1:4)
)
dt[, newvariable := 0]
dt[, newvariable := lengthofstay == max(lengthofstay), by = id]
dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
# If you don't have `dplyr` installed run:
# install.packages("dplyr")

library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
)

df %>%
  # All computations are performed within group by `id`:
  group_by(id) %>%
  # `mutate` creates columns sequentially. We create `lengthofstay` first and
  # then we can use `lengthofstay` in the creation of `newvariable`.
  mutate(
    # `row_number` returns the order of each row within group.
    lengthofstay = row_number(),
    # `lengthofstay == max(lengthofstay)` returns a logical with `FALSE` if the
    # row is not the last element of the group, and `TRUE` otherwise.
    # `as.numeric` then converts `FALSE` to 0 and `TRUE` to 1.
    newvariable = as.numeric(lengthofstay == max(lengthofstay))
  ) %>%
  # We don't need to have the data grouped anymore so we call `ungroup`.
  ungroup()
```

This can be a bit more verbose, but (in my opinion) also better readable.

---

Without comments:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    lengthofstay = row_number(),
    newvariable = as.numeric(lengthofstay == max(lengthofstay))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution that is a bit more general.  It is more general because it groups by `id` and considers adjacent values.  In particular it records a 1 if the observation is the last one for the `id` or if the next value of `lengthofstay` does not equal the current value + 1.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  lengthofstay = c(1:3, 1:2, 1:4)
)


df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(newvariable = ifelse(row_number() == n() | lengthofstay+1 != lead(lengthofstay), 1, 0))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id lengthofstay newvariable
#>   <dbl>        <int>       <dbl>
#> 1     1            1           0
#> 2     1            2           0
#> 3     1            3           1
#> 4     2            1           0
#> 5     2            2           1
#> 6     3            1           0
#> 7     3            2           0
#> 8     3            3           0
#> 9     3            4           1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>